# Use of enumitem breaks Bengali enumeration

Tags: xetex, enumitem, polyglossia, indic

Consider the MWE below. Here, I am trying to use [Bengali numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_numerals) for enumeration as per the solution found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246939/14103).

```
\documentclass{article}

% For bilingual document
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% Bangla
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontit[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}

% English
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Times New Roman used
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

% Bangla numerals
\makeatletter
\def\bengalidigits#1{\expandafter\@bengali@digits #1@}
\def\@bengali@digits#1{%
  \ifx @#1
  \else
    \ifx0#1০\else\ifx1#1১\else\ifx2#1২\else\ifx3#1৩\else\ifx4#1৪\else\ifx5#1৫\else\ifx6#1৬\else\ifx7#1৭\else\ifx8#1৮\else\ifx9#1৯\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \expandafter\@bengali@digits
  \fi
}

\def\bengalinumber#1{\bengalidigits{\number#1}}
\def\bengalinumeral#1{\bengalinumber{\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\renewcommand\theenumi{\bengalinumeral{enumi}}

\makeatother

% \usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item এক
\item দুই
\item তিন
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

The above code works fine as you can see from this output.

[image]

However, as soon as the line, `\usepackage{enumitem}`, is put into action,
all the enumerations get numbered as zeros.

[image]

I need to use `enumitem`, because, without it, I am going to loose a substantial amount of formatting in my lists.

Comment: Where can we get the fonts? I think you have to make `enumitem` aware of this special fonts

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Right [here](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a first version, working for digits only, not for numbers > 9.

In short: `enumitem` needs special counter output information for such setups, i.e. an `\AddEnumerateCounter` macro must be used. The special setup is valid here only for digits, unfortunately.

```
\documentclass{article}

% For bilingual document
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


 \usepackage{enumitem}


% Bangla
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontit[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}

% English
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Times New Roman used
%\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

% Bangla numerals
\makeatletter
\def\bengalidigits#1{\expandafter\@bengali@digits #1}
\def\@bengali@digits#1{%
  \ifcase #1
  ০\or১\or২\or৩\or৪\or৫\or৬\or৭\or৮\or৯\fi
}


\def\bengalinumber#1{\bengalidigits{\number#1}}
\def\bengalinumeral#1{\bengalinumber{\csname c@#1\endcsname}}


\AddEnumerateCounter*{\bengalnumeral}{\bengalinumeral}{5}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bengalinumeral*}]
\item এক
\item দুই
\item তিন
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try to update for larger numbers later on

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. Waiting in anticipation for the complete solution.

Comment: @Masroor: I'll try to update soon. My first trials failed, however

Comment: @Masroor: I failed so far to extend the solution, due to expansion issues. This really bothers me. I am sorry that there's no progress

Comment: Since the current solution serves *my purpose*, I will accept it. But I will keep my hopes open.

Answer (score 1):

The `babel` package provides a Bengali localization of `\arabic` and (as an undocumented bonus feature) `alph`.  If this is satisfactory, you can express the following without defining your own counters.  This will also localize the numbers of pages, chapters, sections, table of contents entries, etc.

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if a glyph is not in the current font
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage[english, bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.counters]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=HarfBuzz, Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX}
\else % XeLaTeX?
  \usepackage[english, bidi=default, layout=sectioning.counters]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX}
\fi

\babelprovide[import, main, maparabic, alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

%% From: https://github.com/potasiyam/Kalpurush
%% A matching font family might be Gentium.
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale = 1.0,
           BoldFont = *,
           BoldFeatures = {FakeBold = 1.1}
          ]{Kalpurush}

\begin{document}

\section*{বাংলায়  enumeration }
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*।]
   \item  1st item
   \item 2nd item
     \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
       \item 1st sub item
       \item 2nd sub item 
     \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Kalpurush sample]

As of June 2020, an incompatibility between `babel` and `fontspec` prevents XeTeX from compiling the MWE correctly, but it works in LuaLaTeX 1.12.0.  XeLaTeX from TeX Live 2019 might also work.

Comment: I've investigated the problem with XeTeX and there is a limitation in the way this engine gets rid of the hyphen, namely, there is no way to git rid of it in XeTeX itself . A trick is to set the hyphenchar to `"200B`, as explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124430/how-to-get-rid-of-the-hyphenchar-in-xelatex . `babel` is assuming this character exists, but sadly not all fonts contain it. So, very likely it must be set by hand.

Comment: @JavierBezos I haven’t liiked into the internals, but would `\iffontchar` work? Although, the character is invisible anyway, so it really shouldn’t be necessary to choose a font to “display” it.

Comment: Very likely. IIR, this would mean `babel` shouldn't rely on `HyphenChar`, which is set when the font is loaded (ie, before we can test if a char exists).