# How do I localize enumeration in Bengali?

Tags: xetex, enumerate, indic, locale

In English, enumeration happens automatically, but it does not work in Bengali. How do I localize the enumeration for Bengali?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Siyam Rupali, feature=0, changecounternumbering=0]{latexbangla}

\begin{document}

\section*{বাংলায়  enumeration }
\begin{enumerate}[(১।)]
 \item  1st item
 \item 2nd item
\begin{enumerate}[(ক)]
\item 1st sub item
\item 2nd sub item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

*But it does output:*

[image]

*I want to get output as:*

[image]

Comment: Probably [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302290/use-of-enumitem-breaks-bengali-enumeration) might help you

Answer (score 1):

The `babel` package supports a Bengali version of `\arabic` and (as an undocumented bonus feature) `\alph`.  This enables you to format your example with `enumitem`, and also localizes the numbers of pages, chapters, sections, table of contents entries, etc.

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if a glyph is not in the current font
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage[english, bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.counters]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=HarfBuzz, Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX}
\else % XeLaTeX?
  \usepackage[english, bidi=default, layout=sectioning.counters]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX}
\fi

\babelprovide[import, main, maparabic, alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

%% From: https://github.com/potasiyam/Kalpurush
%% A matching font family might be Gentium.
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale = 1.0,
           BoldFont = *,
           BoldFeatures = {FakeBold = 1.1}
          ]{Kalpurush}

\begin{document}

\section*{বাংলায়  enumeration }
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*।]
   \item  1st item
   \item 2nd item
     \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
       \item 1st sub item
       \item 2nd sub item 
     \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Kalpurush font sample]

This requires LuaLaTeX 1.12.0 or greater, and as of June 2020, a bug in `fontspec` prevents this MWE from working properly in XeLaTeX.  Until this is fixed, LuaLaTeX from TeX Live 2020 works, and XeLaTeX from TeX Live 2019 might too.

If these don’t meet your needs, you will need to [define your own enumeration counter.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302290/use-of-enumitem-breaks-bengali-enumeration)